# LLVM IR instumentation. how to get the element value the pointer arg is pointing to?

Tags: function, arguments, llvm, instrumentation

I am trying to instrument LLVM IR call instruction. What I want to achieve is to get the arguments of a function call. If the argument is pointer type, then I want to get the element/variable that pointer is pointing to. I know that if I have the argument, I can use

```
getPointerElementType to get the type of element the pointer is pointing to.
```

But how to access the value of element?

Answer (score 5):

You want to

> get the element/variable that pointer is pointing to

This is also called "dereferencing a pointer". This is not something you can do at compile time, but what you **can** do is insert an instruction which does the dereferencing - in other words, [a `load` instruction](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#load-instruction).

Comment: Okay I understand that. But what I want to do is to pass that value to a function in runtime library. Can I directly pass the load instruction as the argument or will have to first store the value to some Value (e.g of type int) and then pass to the function?

Comment: If the function wants a pointer, you can transfer it as-is. If it wants the pointed-to value, you need to transfer the `load` instruction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `load` function from IRBuilder package. Here is reference from official llvmlite documentation:

• IRBuilder.load(ptr, name='', align=None)
Load value from pointer ptr. If align is passed, it should be a Python integer specifying the guaranteed
pointer alignment.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).